# how to detect network event in cocoa osx

Tags: cocoa, macos, networking, events

Is it possible to make sure my thread reacts on whenever there is network available ? Basically my thread should automatically get event that network is available and perform certain task.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a way of getting network change event using growl framework.
Added code on top of it to receive network change event.
Growl framework can be found at http://growl.info/documentation/developer/

Comment: if this is the correct answer than you should change the title to "how to detect network event in cocoa osx USING GROWL". Some of us can't just use a third party for everything...

Answer (score 5):

Yes you can, use Reachability APIs in SystemConfiguration.framework. See [here](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/DOCUMENTATION/Networking/Conceptual/SystemConfigFrameworks/SC_ReachConnect/SC_ReachConnect.html). A sample code (for iphone) is available [here](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/samplecode/Reachability/). The parts concerning the reachability APIs should be usable for OS X, too.

To use the APIs, you need to understand an OS X specific concept of "run loops." See [here](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Multithreading/RunLoopManagement/RunLoopManagement.html).

Comment: I wanted asynchronous way of receiving notification of network change event.